# Merge PowerPoint Slides using Apache POI XSLF: How to Resolve 'UnsupportedOperationException' When Copying Shapes Between Slides?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

I'm trying to merge PowerPoint slides using Apache POI XSLF and encountering an 'UnsupportedOperationException' when attempting to copy shapes between slides. Looking for guidance on a workaround or alternative approach to successfully merge shapes without facing this issue.

```
    XMLSlideShow ppt = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("source.pptx"));

    XSLFSlide mergedSlide = ppt.createSlide();

    XSLFSlide slide1 = ppt.getSlides().get(0);
    XSLFSlide slide2 = ppt.getSlides().get(1);

    for (XSLFShape shape : slide1.getShapes()) {
        XSLFShape newShape = mergedSlide.createAutoShape();
        newShape.getXmlObject().set(shape.getXmlObject().copy());
        mergedSlide.addShape(newShape); // THIS LINE THROWS EXCEPTION
    }
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide2.getShapes()) {
        XSLFShape newShape = mergedSlide.createAutoShape();
        newShape.getXmlObject().set(shape.getXmlObject().copy());
        mergedSlide.addShape(newShape);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661090/how-to-duplicate-a-shape-apache-poi/71681791#71681791

Comment: @AxelRichter this is cloning but not merging. i want merge first and second slide into new one slide :)

Comment: This then is the same problem though. Copying all shapes from slide 1 and slide 2 to merged slide. Then delete slide 1 and slide 2.

Comment: yes but in provided code it doesn't copying all contents of slides into new one